# Mysterious NaN in console.log. Attempting a short physics experiment

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, gravity, particles

So I have pinpointed what I believe to be the problem here.  Though, I am having a hard time understanding why exactly the console.log(particles[index].x); call outputs "NaN".  It should be a number.  So, why isn't it?  Not sure why this is down-vote worthy, can someone explain this to me?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight,
c = document.getElementById('c'),
ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var center = {x:width/2, y:height/2};


var particles = [];
var totalParticles = width/50;
var size = 20;

function init(){
    for (var i = 0; i < totalParticles; i++) {
        addParticle(i);
    }
    drawParticle(center.x, center.y, 20, particles[1].c);

    setInterval(update, 40);
}

function update(){

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        applyForce(i);
    }
}

function applyForce(index){

    console.log(particles[index].x);
    var rx = Math.abs(particles[index].x - center.x);
    var ry = Math.abs(particles[index].y - center.y);

    var sign = {x:1, y:1};
    if (particles[index].x > center.x) {
        sign.x = -sign.x;
    } else {
        sign.x = sign.x;
    }

    if (particles[index].y > center.y) {
        sign.y = -sign.y;
    } else {
        sign.y = sign.y;
    }   

    //just use size for mass, center has mass 1
    var force = {
        x:(sign.x*particles[index].s)/Math.pow(rx, 2),
        y:(sign.y*particles[index].s)/Math.pow(ry, 2)
    };



    addForce(index, force);

}

function addForce(index, force){

    particles[index].v.x += force.x;
    particles[index].v.y += force.y;

    particles[index].x = particles[index].x + particles[index].v.x;
    particles[index].y = particles[index].y + particles[index].v.y;

    drawParticle(particles[index].x, particles[index].y, particles[index].s, particles[index].c);

}

function drawParticle(x,y,size,color){

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=color;
    ctx.fill();
}

function addParticle(index){

        size = Math.random() * size + 10;
        var y = Math.random() * height;
        var x = width - 10;
        if (index%2) {
            x = 10;
            console.log("even");
        }

        particles.push({s:size, 
                        x:x, 
                        y:y, 
                        v:(Math.random() * 2) + 4, 
                        c:'#' + (Math.random() * 0x313131 + 0xaaaaaa | 0).toString(16)});

        return;

}

init();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you found in debugging so far? What "index" when that happens?  Have you added `console.log()` calls in the `addParticle()` function?

Comment: Yes I have and particles[index].x exists at the bottom of addParticle() before the return; call.  So, when update is called, it ought to be present in particles[] for use in applyForce().

Comment: size = Math.random() * size + 10; in your AddParticle function at a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `particles[index].v.x` and `particles[index].v.y` are always `undefined`. So, when you sum these `undefined` values:

```
particles[index].x = particles[index].x + particles[index].v.x;
particles[index].y = particles[index].y + particles[index].v.y;
```

`particles[index].x` and `particles[index].y` also become `undefined`.

Comment: This is true!  Not sure why that gave NaN for `console.log(particles[index].x)` when I didn't even use `particles[index].v.y ` till later, but, this gets me way closer and the program draws now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You assign a number to the v property...

```
particles.push({s:size, 
                x:x, 
                y:y, 
                v:(Math.random() * 2) + 4, 
                c:'#' + (Math.random() * 0x313131 + 0xaaaaaa | 0).toString(16)});
```

Later on you access it like this...

```
 particles[index].v.x += force.x;
 particles[index].v.y += force.y;
```

Both v.x and v.y are undefined.

```
> 1 + undefined
Nan
```

A number plus undefined is not a number.

Comment: Thanks for the response Bart.  So a proper argument to pass would look like `v:{x:(Math.random() * 2) + 4, y:(Math.random() * 2) + 4},` am I correct?  I'm new to JavaScript and not used to this sort of declaration.

Comment: @paperview Yes! That would be the right way to create the x and y properties